# Electron get height of titlebar / Set 2nd window on same Y coordinate?

Tags: node.js, electron, titlebar

Right now I am writing a small app with NodeJS/Electron.
It's basically a map with a customer list, but the customer list should also be able to pop out into a second window.

So far so good, everything is working as it should, but I want the second window to be aligned with the right border of the first window and it should be on the same height/y-coordinate. Like this:

[windows aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEBbI.png)

But the problem is that when I set my second windows bounds to the same bounds of the first window it causes the second window to have an offset. And the offset is exactly the height of the titlebar.

See here:

[windows not aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e72wk.png)

I'm trying to figure this out for around two weeks now, but I can't seem to find a reliable way to always get that offset. The app will run on Linux and Windows machines, so I can't set a fixed offset.

This is the code I use right now, where the offset occurs:

```
var window = new BrowserWindow({width: 1000, height:800});
var bounds = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay().bounds;
var wBounds = window.getBounds();
window.setBounds({ 
    x: Math.ceil(bounds.width / 2 - wBounds.width / 2),
    y: Math.ceil(bounds.height / 2 - wBounds.height / 2),
    height: wBounds.height,
    width: wBounds.width
});
wBounds = window.getBounds();
extWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 600 , height: wBounds.height , x: wBounds.x + wBounds.width , y: wBounds.y});

//in my case window.getBounds().y -> 168, extWindow.getBounds().y -> 168
```

where `window` is my main window and `extwindow` is the second one.
When reading `window.getBounds().y` and `extWindow.getBounds().y` they're the same. So what is the problem here ? `extWindow` is **not** a child of `window`!

Is there any way to either get the height of the titlebar or disable the new window being offset?

I'm using:

- Electron 2.0.5
- Electron-Builder 20.21.2
- Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon 3.8.8

3m7ecc

Comment: Have you maybe tried initialize your window with `useContentSize: true`? (has effect on size though)

Comment: Just tried that, but it makes no difference besides increasing the height. The offset stays the same!